# Datatable sorting is not working for dd-mm-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date, datatables

I want to sort date on datatable. I want it to do in this format `D-M-Y`, but it doesn't work.

When I change the format to `Y-M-D` it works. But I need in this format `D-M-Y`.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#est').dataTable({
               "bProcessing": true,
               "bServerSide": true,
               "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/tendersdatatable',
               "aaSorting": [
                   [3, "desc"]
               ],
               "bJQueryUI": true,
               "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
               "iDisplayStart ": 20,
               "oLanguage": {},
               "fnInitComplete": function () {
                   //oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
               },
               'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                   $.ajax({
                       'dataType': 'json',
                       'type': 'POST',
                       'url': sSource,
                       'data': aoData,
                       'success': fnCallback
                   });
               }
           });
           $('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('form-control').attr('placeholder', 'Search...').css('margin-right', "4%");
           $('.dataTables_length select').addClass('form-control');
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me if anyone need's it . 
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2467/need-help-for-sorting-date-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for date-time sorting. [Source](http://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). It does have moment.js as a dependancy though.

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D-M-Y');
```

Comment: Tanks, that is what I was looking for. I was trying using "dd-mm-YYYY" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are [sorting plug-ins](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/) available, however none of them except [datetime-moment](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment) supports the format you need. But `datetime-moment` plug-in has dependency with moment.js.

However it could be done by defining a custom sorting method `date-dmy` before you initialize your data table.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-dmy-pre": function ( a ) {
        if (a == null || a == "") {
            return 0;
        }
        var date = a.split('-');
        return (date[2] + date[1] + date[0]) * 1;
    },

    "date-dmy-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "date-dmy-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );
```

To use this custom type, you need to use `aoColumnDefs` to set desired column type as shown below. I'm using index `0` to set type of the first column. Other initialization options are omitted for simplicity.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sType": "date-dmy", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin. You can sort it adding a hidden element.

Convert the date to the format YYYYMMDD and prepend to the actual value (DD/MM/YYYY) in the , wrap it in an element, set style display:none; to the elements. Now the date sort will work as a normal sort. The same can be applied to date-time sort.

HTML

```
<table id="data-table">
   <tr>
     <td><span>YYYYMMDD</span>DD/MM/YYYY</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If you are using rails as me the sintaxys will be like this:

```
<td> 
    <span> 
        <%= youmodel.created_at.strftime("%Y%m%d") %> 
    </span> 
    <%= youmodel.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %> 
</td>
```

CSS

```
#data-table span {
    display:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
    function (sData) {
        if (sData !== null && sData.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20|21)\d\d$/)) {
            return 'date-uk';
        }
        return null;
    }
);
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-uk-pre": function (a) {
    if (a == null || a == "") {
        return 0;
    }
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
},

"date-uk-asc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},

"date-uk-desc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
});
```